# How to convert base64 index to plain string in PHP?

Tags: php

How to convert base64 index to plain string in PHP?

$let = chr(bindec($let));

It returns :

I need to convert to String.

```
foreach($binaryArray as $binary){
        $let = str_pad($binary, 6, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        //$let = bindec($let);
        $let = chr(bindec($let));
        $base64String .= $let;
    }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and output that you want to convert?

Comment: input char index: 19,16.
the output should be: T,Q

instead of returning TQ, I received two boxes.

Comment: Ah, looking at [the Base64 table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it starts to make sense to me.

Comment: I tried. But I cannot return a string. It returns some box charatcters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, looking at [the Base64 table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it starts to make sense to me. I think it can be as simple as this:

```
$binaryArray = [19,16];        
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
$base64String = "";
foreach ($binaryArray as $index) {
    $base64String .= $chars[$index];
}
echo $base64String;
```

This does return "TQ". See: [PHP fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94ad23db082989a587b3b0b0e7515b2887f246fa)